# Multi-indexing in Pandas - Want the first level to be count and the second to be datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, multi-index

Been stuck for a while on the following problem - what I want is to create a DataFrame which is multi-indexed so that the first level has a count of all batches of data and the second level to be datetime objects of each data point in the batch. The below picture should help clarify my meaning:

**Update**

So I have managed to do what I intended and while I know this is probably not the easiest way to do so, it works. Happy for others to propose new solutions.

```
# Create the two arrays (each will be a level in the MultiIndex)
Outputs = 12 # The number of dates we want in each batch (batch size)
index_arrays = [y for x in range(len(x_test_data)) for y in [x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, x]]
date_arrays = [df.loc[df['2012-10-31':].index.date[i] : df['2012-10-31':].index.date[i+Outputs-1]].index.date.tolist() for i in range(len(x_test_data))]

# Zip them together
u = []

for i in range(len(date_arrays)):

    u.append(list(zip(*[[i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i,i], date_arrays[i]])))

# Flatten the list to make next step easier
flatList = [item for elem in u for item in elem]

# Create the MultiIndex
indexer = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(flatList, names = ['Batches', 'Dates'])
```

[image]

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Can you create some code to generate your input dataframe also?

Comment: [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html) objects, including MultiIndex, must be [immutable](https://realpython.com/courses/immutability-python/), therefore you cannot have ranges, arrays, lists, or other objects as index keys. This immutability guarantees that looking up a key can reliably be used to retrieve the corresponding value. So, there's no way to do what you're asking and pandas isn't designed to support it. Can you explain why you're trying to do this? maybe we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @U12-Forward The desired output is like the picture above - except the dates are not in a tuple but how dates are in 'normal indexing'

Comment: @ScottBoston Please see my updated original question for the dataframe

Comment: @MichaelDelgado this may seem very tough to explain but I will try. So I have an LSTM which takes n previous data points as input to make a 12-step prediction into the future. The output is a tensor. What I want to do is map the outputs to a dataframe that is indexed by date so I can easily see which predictions correspond to each date, while also knowing the 'batch' it was. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @TheQuant  You need to include a fully reproducible example in this question.  It is, atleast for me, difficult to see what you are starting with an where you are a going.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: specifically, what is `data`? is that a list of lists? what is `test_set_predictions`? Check out this article on creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - it's really hard for us to help without one. Thank you :)